# Issue Consuming a Rest API from ColdFusion

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to consume a Rest API from ColdFusion and I ran into this error. The code and the error is below

```
<cfset theURL = "https://api.dev.net/rest/test/encrypt/124123">
<cfhttp url="#theURL#" result="value" method="get" username="XXX" password="XXX">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/xml">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/xml">
</cfhttp>
```

Error:
400 Bad Request. Content Type not specified

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: The error message is explicit: the request is bad, because Content Type was expected but not received. Since you've apparently not provided the real API URL, nobody here can do more than make guesses as to what is expected - like maybe you need a different type attribute or to remove/replace the hyphen with a space or whatever. The documentation for whatever service this is will almost certainly provide an example which contains this information...

Comment: It looks like your content-type is correctly formed, but in the example, you're not actually sending any XML in the body of the request. That means you're either not sending content that you should be, or your content-type is suspect. As Peter says, its worth posting the actual API URL or a link to any docs you have

Answer (score 0):

`<cfhttpparam>` can accept **XML** as the type (type="XML"), which sets content-type of the request to 'text/xml'. the value attribute in this case should contain the body of the xml request. so try

```
<cfhttpparam type="XML" value="#your_XML_string#">
```

and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that you are setting the method to "get". This is used to retrieve a file. If you are using resftul services you "post" to the service.

The next issue you will have is that as it is a SSL service, you will need to install the SSL cert into your trusted key store. (Google this).

The next issue you might come across is where the service 'zips' up the response. If this happens google for cfhttp compression and you will get your answer.

Comment: If you are retrieving a resource, then you GET. POST is used to create a resource and PUT to update that resource. You won't necessarily need to install an SSL certificate either, as the target service may use a certificate countersigned by a trusted authority (Thawte, Verisign etc). The error message indicates that you're probably connecting fine. On compression, if the server is honouring  the Accept-Encoding header properly, then you ought to be ok. To test this out, install and run Fiddler and use proxyserver and proxyport attributes on cfhttp to monitor the traffic

Comment: You are correct in general http terms, but CFHTTP post method is the same as using a form with the method="post". Restful services use post method, unless you are using the get method and adding url variables. As to SSL, the issue is that the CF server doesn't handle SSL unless it has the SSL cert installed. Not sure how much SSL work you've done with CF server. Adobe give you instructions on how to install SSL certs for use with CF. I'm sure you know better.